# consuming webservice laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, web-services

I have two projects in laravel, one only with my vision (**AppView**) and another with the web service (**AppWs**), in my web service I have the following route
Route **project AppWs**
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'],function(){

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function(){

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'tipoprojeto'], function(){           

            Route::get('','Painel\TipoProjetoController@All');

         });        
    }); 
});
```

when I access http://localhost/WebServiceApp/public/api/user/tipoprojeto/

it returns me an array with all the data, until then all right.

in my other project, I have a TypeProjectController controller and I have my index () method (**AppView**), so how can I retrieve the webservice data to load here?

EDIT

**AppWs** responsible for manipulating the data

```
public function All(){
    return $this->ModelTipoProjeto->paginate(5);
  }
```

**AppView** responsible for displaying data
**Route::resource('/Painel/TipoProjeto', 'Painel\TipoProjetoController');**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $getData = `http://localhost/WebServiceApp/public/api/user/tipoprojeto/` // <~~

        return view('Painel.TipoProjeto.index');
    }
```

Retrieve the data that the AppWebservice link returns

Comment: `Route::get('/','Painel\TipoProjetoController@All');` you're missing the slash .

Comment: This is not the problem, my question is how the index () function that is in the controller of my AppView project can retrieve the data that the AppWs project returns in its All method

Comment: add the all method here ...

Comment: Use Guzzle. And define your routes properly.

Comment: Can I only consume through Guzzle?

Comment: right, I have to say you are a bit lost here.

Comment: can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

First of all in order to consume an external service you have to perfrom a http request towards the endpoint where you intend to get the data form.

Your endpoing: `http://localhost/WebServiceApp/public/api/user/tipoprojeto/`

Install guzzle which is a php curl wrapper to perform http calls.
In your root dir open command line and inject guzzle in your project by firing :

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Make sure you import guzzle at the top of the controller by adding

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

Then go to your index method and do the following:

```
public function index(){

// Create a client with a base URI
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://localhost/WebServiceApp/public/api/user/tipoprojeto/']);

// Send a request to http://localhost/WebServiceApp/public/api/user/tipoprojeto/
$response = $client->request('GET', 'test');

// $response contains the data you are trying to get, you can do whatever u want with that data now. However to get the content add the line

$contents = $response->getBody()->getContents();

dd($contents);
}
```

`$contents` contains the data now you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Okay, I'll follow in your footsteps, do you think it's wrong for me to work with a web service in laravel and an application only with the vision also in laravel? Do you think that for application with the vision I should only use a native php for example or a simple html e jquery how requisitions ajax?

Comment: if you want a build a serverice api and a client to consume then you should do this.

Comment: Excuse me, should I do this? Use laravel in both my web service and my view?