# consuming web service with laravel and guzzle

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to retrieve some information on my controller 
using GuzzleHttp

```
use \GuzzleHttp\Client;
class ClientsController extends Controller
{     
    public function index()
    {
        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://localhost/systeml/public/ws/clients']);

        $response = $client->request('GET', '');    
        $contents = $response->getBody()->getContents();    
        dd($contents);
}
```

when I run this command the following problem appears

> (1/1) ServerException Server error: `GET
>   http://localhost/systeml/public/ws/clients`
>   resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:

the guzzle is running normal and having problems trying to access the other local server?

Comment: is your other server running ?

Comment: Yes, they're on the same machine.

Comment: use postman then to fire calls towards your web service first then do it through the code.

Comment: I was working on both projects via wamp server, so I started one by php artisan, and right, thank you

Comment: accept the answer here, since I helped you to get to the right path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609944/consuming-webservice-laravel/48610311?noredirect=1#comment84218342_48610311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure in the other project you run `php artisan serve`  in the root directory of the project.

And use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613305/sending-data-with-put-post-to-a-webservice-in-laravel