# Sending data with put / post to a webservice in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, guzzle

I'm trying to create a dynamic method to send / receive my data with my webservice using guzzle and laravel

I have the following structure in my controller

```
class TipoProjetoController extends Controller
{
    private $Tabela = 'tipoprojeto';    
    public function AppWebService($Who, $Type, $Data)
    {
        $Client = new Client(['base_uri' => config('constants.caminhoWS').$Who]);        
        $response = $Client->request($Type, $Data);
        return $response->getBody()->getContents();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $Dados = $this->AppWebService($this->Tabela,'GET','');
        $Titulo = 'Tipos de Projeto';

        $jsonObj = json_decode($Dados);
        $Obj = $jsonObj->data;

        return view('Painel.TipoProjeto.index',compact('Obj','Titulo') );
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('Painel.TipoProjeto.create-edit');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $Dados = $this->AppWebService($this->Tabela.'/'.$id,'GET','');

        if( $Dados == null )
            return redirect()->route('TipoProjeto.index');
        else
        {
            $Objeto = json_decode($Dados);
            return view('Painel.TipoProjeto.create-edit',compact('Objeto'));
        }

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $Dados = $this->AppWebService($this->Tabela.'/'.$id, 'PUT', ''); 
        dd($Dados);  
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Until then everything worked perfectly in my `Index` and `Edit` method, because the method of sending is `GET`. now I am trying to send a request to the server with the `PUT` method and I am not getting.

The AppWebService method has as the first parameter the name of the route that I am accessing, the type and the information that I am going to pass.

I tried this way

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $Dados = $this->AppWebService($this->Tabela.'/'.$id, 'PUT', ['data'=>'$request']); 
    dd($Dados);  
}
```

and the error was

> (1/1) InvalidArgumentException URI must be a string or UriInterface

my request received from my client was

```
dd($request)

Request {#38 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure {#154 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure {#156 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#40 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#39 ▶}
  +query: ParameterBag {#46 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#42 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#43 ▶}
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#41 ▶}
  +headers: HeaderBag {#44 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/Painel/TipoProjeto/1"
  #requestUri: "/index.php/Painel/TipoProjeto/1"
  #baseUrl: "/index.php"
  #basePath: null
  #method: "PUT"
  #format: null
  #session: Store {#185 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
}
```

as my application is in laravel and my webservice too, is it any problem that I send the request this way? or do I have to extract and send it?
and how do I send the put and post methods to my dynamic function?

[EDIT] File Web Service, Route and Controller

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'],function(){

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function(){

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'tipoprojeto'], function(){           

            Route::get('/','Painel\TipoProjetoController@All');

            Route::get('{id}','Painel\TipoProjetoController@Get');

            Route::post('','Painel\TipoProjetoController@Save');

            Route::put('{id}','Painel\TipoProjetoController@Update');

            Route::delete('{id}','Painel\TipoProjetoController@Delete');            

        });     
    }); 
});
```

Webservice method that receives my request

```
class TipoProjetoController extends Controller
{
  public function Update(Request $request, $id){
      return 'Change data of id:'.$id;
  }

}
```

Comment: don't you mean `['data'=>$request]` instead of `['data'=>'$request']` ?

Comment: about this `$Client = new Client(['base_uri' => config('constants.caminhoWS').$Who]);`

could you extract `config('constants.caminhoWS').$Who` into its own variable and dump it, make sure it's correct?

Comment: can we see your routes file as well please?

Comment: I edited the question and put it, if it has not been very clear I can provide more things so that you can help me, if possible

Comment: what about the route file of the URL on the webservice? (The URL guzzle is PUTting to when you hit the update method)

Comment: I think your route definition is wrong `Route::put('{id}','Painel\TipoProjetoController@Update');` should be `Route::put('/{id}','Painel\TipoProjetoController@Update');`

Comment: and what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: but for my requests get it works without the / and the version is 5.4.36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `['data'=>$request]` instead of `['data'=>'$request']`

you're also using `$Client->request();` wrong. The second parameter should be the URI, not an array, hence your error.

Also the base URI is not meant to be used that way,
so instead try

```
$Client = new Client();
$url = config('constants.caminhoWS').$Who;    
$response = $Client->request($Type,$url, $Data);
```

(if you are going to use a base URI, use the second parameter in `$Client->request()` to pass the rest of the URL, like

```
$Client = new Client(['base_uri' => config('constants.caminhoWS')]);  
$response = $Client->request($Type, $Who, $Data);
```

Then Guzzle will construct the URL...
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#making-a-request

Comment: This gave a new error, (1/1) InvalidArgumentException URI must be a string or UriInterface

Comment: esulted in a `405 Method Not Allowed` response:
<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: is the method `PUT` listed in your route for that Controller action?

Comment: I'm going to add the route and the webservice method

Comment: I just commented on this line in my web service // // App \ Http \ Middleware \ VerifyCsrfToken :: class file, and it worked, but if I put it in again the problem occurs

Comment: ah yeah you need to pass a CSRF token with your data

Comment: but I step along with my parents have the itoken

Comment: sorry I don't understand your last comment

Comment: Help-me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649150/upload-images-to-web-service-with-laravel